# css min() and max() functions vs min-width and max-width

Tags: css, max, min

I've seen people using min() and max() css functions instead max-width or min-width props like that:

```
width: min(440px, 100%);
```

Instead of classic:

```
width: 440px;
max-width: 100%;
```

Which is better? I mean, is any performance caveat using min() or max() or is it good to use?
In my case, I think the `max-width` way is more understandable than `min()` function, what do you think?

Thanks

Comment: It's not the same thing.

Comment: `min()` is a function, but `max-width`  is a property. With `width: min(440px, 100%)` it calculates both values and gets the lowest one to assign to `width` as a suggestion. While `max-width` is a property that prevents the calculated width from surpassing a specific value.

Comment: Your question is opinion based. With CSS you have a lot of ways to achieve the same thing. Pick the one you want.

Comment: Ok, so I don't need to worry about performance issues, that's my major preocupation. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see, they give the same result.

```css
.d1 {
  width: min(440px, 100%);
  background: pink;
}

.d2 {
  width: 440px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">1</div>
<div class="d2">2</div>
```